# Arithmetic over unsigned long integers in z3

Tags: z3

Which is the preferred method of dealing with arithmetic (addition and comparisons primarily) over unsigned long integers in Z3 Solver ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what you want.
If you want to be bit-precise, than use bit-vectors.  Otherwise you can use integers or even reals.

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently using integers, but I could not found the method for defining 'long' constants. I could only find the one accepting integers and I am running into overflow issues.

Comment: Z3_mk_int64 or Z3_mk_numeral